# Find only duplicate values in associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

This is my array output -

```
print_r($array_email);

    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
            [1] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
            [2] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
            [3] => v@gmail.com
            [4] => v@gmail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => vikastyagi1987@gmail.com
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => vikastyagi1987@gmail.com
        )

)
```

Here i have tried - (but not working)

```
function get_duplicates( $array ) {
                return array_unique( array_diff_assoc( $array, array_unique( $array ) ) );
            }

print_r(get_duplicates($array_email));
```

I need output like that-

```
Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
                [2] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
                [4] => v@gmail.com
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => vikastyagi1987@gmail.com
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your requirement correctly:

```
array_map(function($elem) {
    return array_unique($elem);
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain me how to use it ?

Comment: I may be completely misunderstanding the question, and I've certainly got no idea how the 2 arrays in the example given actually relate to each other... but doesn't this give the exact opposite of "Find duplicates" in that it removes them rather than finds them?

Comment: @vikastyagi This call returns the filtered array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$value) {
    $value = array_unique($value);
});

$arr = array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR);
```

`array_walk` will remove duplicates inside inner arrays. `array_unique` will do the rest.